# What is prototypical abstract data type?

Tags: java, algorithm, oop, data-structures

My current knowledge of ADT states that its a blueprint and all the real implementation should should follow the rules / contracts described in the blueprint.

But while reading a book on Algorithm I found this term  `The symbol table is a prototypical abstract data type` what do we mean by **prototypical** in this statement?

Answer (score 1):

An abstract data type is a mathematical model for data types, that means it describes possible values and operations for this data type, and not its concrete representation and implementation.

Prototypical means that it serves as illustration of typical qualities, and can be used as base for creating something derivative.